# How to set long text in a textview with a continuation mark at the end of the textview

Tags: android, textview

I have a textview with fixed height. I want to set a long text, but text comes at the last line getting cut by half, I want to avoid it and want to show a continuation symbol. I am giving an image here, I wan to achieve it like in the image.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`ellipsize`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aellipsize) attribute of `TextView`. By setting :

```
  <TextView
        ....
        android:ellipsize="end">
  </TextView>
```

if the text is longer than your `TextView` you will have dots(`...`) at the end of the `TextView`.

Answer (score 2):

Two line of string only possible to do like this. set ellipsize = end in text view properties.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `\n` and special symbols from google code.